# Combine pairs of matching items to matching groups (3+ items)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, duplicates, combinations

So, I have a csv-file with pairs of matching images (more or less identical), as per below:

```
File1;File2
File3;File4
File5;File1
File2;File5
...
```

I want to remove duplicate images based on this data. The csv file is from a third-party program that matches images based on the contents, but the problem is that it only matches pairs, and ignores if a file has been matched earlier (i.e. groups of three of more duplicates are not listed together)

The critical point is the third and fourth rows in the above example, where File1 also matches File5, and File2 matches File5, so all three files are duplicates. But if I just delete files based on the data I might remove all of them (if I remove the second of each row).

So I'm trying to make a list of groups of matching files, to ensure I always keep one of them. Above example should be like:

```
File1;File2;File5
File3;File4
...
```

Here my code, which doesn't seem to do it. The csv-file is read into a list (_data) of pairs. The final list is self.__map.

```
    _exists = [ ]
    for _match in _data:
        _first = _match[ 0 ] in _exists
        _second = _match[ 1 ] in _exists
        if not _first and not _second:
            self.__map.append( _match )
            _exists.append( _match[ 0 ] )
            _exists.append( _match[ 1 ] )
        elif _first and not _second:
            for _node in self.__map:
                if _first in _node:
                    _node.append( _match[ 1 ] )
                    _exists.append( _match[ 1 ] )
                    break
        elif _second and not _first:
            for _node in self.__map:
                if _second in _node:
                    _node.append( _match[ 0 ] )
                    _exists.append( _match[ 0 ] )
                    break
```

Can't see why it won't work, but when I check self.__map it doesn't contain all the files from the csv file.

There's probably a simpler way entirely to do it, so feel free to suggest better methods.

Comment: You may want to use a library like `networkx` to find cycles.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected something like networkx would exist for it. I'm not sufficiently well versed in it to grasp what I need but maybe I managed to find rhe same type of problem solved using it at https://stackoverflow.com/a/6206011/4038380

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code does not work due to these two lines.

```
if _first in _node:
```

and

```
if _second in _node:
```

In the beginning `_first` and `_second` was evaluated to be Boolean values denoting if first file and second file is already identified or not. however in those lines they are being treated as the first and second item respectively. Change `_first` to  `_match[0]` and `_second` to `_match[1]`. It should work.

Or else we can implement this way as well.

```
files = [
    ["File1","File2"],
    ["File3","File4"],
    ["File5","File1"],
    ["File2","File5"],
]

# list of sets. each set contains duplicate/related images. set is used to avoid duplicates. we
# can use list of list here as well. in that case we need add additional logic to handle
# duplicates later
map_of_duplicates = []
for file1, file2 in files:
    new_entry = True
    for match in map_of_duplicates:
        if file1 in match and file2 in match:
            # if both files are present in the match set do nothing
            new_entry = False
            break
        elif file1 in match:
            # if only file1 is present in the match set then add file2 to match set
            new_entry = False
            match.add(file2)
            break
        elif file2 in match:
            #if only file2 is present in the match set then add file1 to the match set
            new_entry = False
            match.add(file1)
            break
    # if after the inner for loop new_entry flag is still true that means none of the files were found in the map and
    # this is indeed a new entry
    if new_entry:
        map_of_duplicates.append(set((file1, file2)))

print(map_of_duplicates)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following approach:

```
data = """File1;File2
File3;File4
File5;File1
File2;File5"""

# Make sure you have a list of set (and not a list of list)
l = [set(_.split(";")) for _ in data.split("\n")]
print(l)
# [{'File1', 'File2'}, {'File4', 'File3'}, {'File1', 'File5'}, {'File5', 'File2'}]

# Add first item
out = [l[0]]
# Iterate over the list input
for pair in l[1:]:
    added = False
    # Iterate over output (already visited pairs)
    for i, pair_out in enumerate(out):
        # if any element of the pair has already been visited
        if any(file_ in pair_out for file_ in pair):
            # Update output
            out[i] = pair_out.union(pair)
            added = True
            # Exit loop
            break
    # If pair not found: append the pair
    if not added: out.append(pair)

print(out)
# [{'File1', 'File5', 'File2'}, {'File4', 'File3'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach

```
from collections import defaultdict

input_data = """File1;File2
File3;File4
File5;File1
File2;File5"""

data = [d.split(';') for d in input_data.split("\n")]
result = defaultdict(list)

# Create the full list of matches
for d1, d2 in data:
    result[d1].append(d2)
    result[d2].append(d1)

# Start with all the keys
keep = list(result.keys())

# Remove any keys that are repeats
for key in result:
    if key in keep:
        for repeated in result[key]:
            if repeated in keep:
                keep.remove(repeated)

# Pick only the ones we want to keep
result = {k: v for k, v in result.items() if k in keep}
```